# I want to create a loop to write data from different text files to single excel file

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to print data from some text files in a folder into excel file.
i want each file data to be in each column. I can only write the data from all files into single column. can you help me on how to do that?

```py
import glob, xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Example2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
column = 0

fileslist = []
for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/sahithpixels/Documents/SDN/*"):
    fileslist.append(file)
    a = file.strip('\n')
#    print(a)

filedata = []
for line in fileslist:
    with open(line, 'r') as inputfile:
        f = inputfile.read().rstrip('\n\n')
        filedata.append(f)
for line1 in filedata:
    x = line1.split('\n\n')
    for line2 in x:
        worksheet.write_string(row, column, line2)
        row += 1
print(filedata)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you first read the data from all files into the `filedata` array. After that you can no longer tell which line came from which file and thus you cannot increment the `column` counter. You have to nest the two loops. Something similar to this:

```
filedata = []
for line in fileslist:
    row = 0
    with open(line, 'r') as inputfile:
        f = inputfile.read().rstrip('\n\n')
        filedata.append(f)
        x = f.split('\n\n')
        for line2 in x:
            worksheet.write_string(row, column, line2)
            row += 1
    column += 1
print(filedata)
```

Comment: i think the next loop will start from the next row and column where the previous loop left over.

Comment: And i tried the hint you gave me, it does the what i said above. if first file is written on colum 1 , ends at row 5 the second file starts from column 2 row 6, which is supposed to start from column 2 row 0 and so on.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. Of course you have to reset the row for each file. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tested by placing row = 0 above the the for loop. But thanks again.